# Toggle Menu bar when hover on menuico

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have created Menu bar and menu icon

What i am trying to do is when hover on menu icon the menu bar should be toggled from left side but it is not working so please help me to do it...

follow the link to [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/mandar262/pen/OpXveQ?editors=1100)

Following is My code

```css
body {
  background-color: #F2D7EE;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menuico {
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 170px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navmenu {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #0E103D;
  height: 100%;
  //width: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  color: #F2D7EE;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mainMenu {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.mainMenu:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuico:hover .navmenu {
  width: 150px;
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="navmenu">
  <div class="menuico"></div>
  <div class="menuico"></div>
  <div class="menuico"></div>
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="mainMenu">AboutMe</div>
    <div class="mainMenu">contact-us</div>
    <div class="mainMenu">Project</div>
    <div class="mainMenu">Blog</div>
    <div class="mainMenu">More</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to reorganise your markup a little. Reason already explained in the answer below. See this - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/cyw58uux/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not control ANY element on others hover, only those which are inside the element or after it.

```css
.menu {
width:20%;
left:-20%;
height:100%;
position:fixed;
background-color:red;
transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.icon:hover + .menu {
left:0%
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">icon</div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help upvote for your  wounderful  answer